# Digital radio to Bluetooth bridge

Tags: radio, bluetooth, digital-audio, audio-codec

I'm studying the possibility of building a bridge from DAB+ (digital radio) towards Bluetooth. The reason is that all the good quality DAB+ tuners are really expensive and the cheap ones usually have an amplifier included; besides that, it seems an interesting project.

I was looking into the Silicon Labs Si4684 chip; it comes with a digital output (I2S) for the PCM audio signal, and it seems that I can't get the original HE-ACC encoded stream from this chip.

Since I want to send this audio directly to a Bluetooth amplifier, I would have to encode it again, maybe also with HE-ACC.

1. Will I lose audio quality by lossy compression of the stream that already had been compressed/decompressed before? Is there any way to recompress so I don't lose quality?
2. Do you know of any alternatives to get the raw digital stream of DAB+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Will I lose audio quality by lossy compression of the stream that already had been compressed/decompressed before?

If you used the exact same encoder as the station used, synchronized with the exact same encoding settings, the same quantization would happen and you would get the exact same bitstream. That's not going to happen, so unless you use way better quality settings for your encoder (and thus, higher bit rate), you'd probably lose quality.

However, since your BT connection is far closer range, it can do much higher bitrate than your DAB+ stream, and you can and will use much higher quality / higher bitrate, and the quality loss will either be none or not noticeable.

So, I wouldn't worry too much about this. Just use the best codec your bluetooth link allows for.

> 2. Do you know of any alternatives to get the raw digital stream of DAB+?

Sure. Just go the SDR route; multiple open source implementations exist (e.g., [gr-dab](https://github.com/kit-cel/gr-dab), [welle.io](https://github.com/AlbrechtL/welle.io), and their predecessors and forks), and by just using their facilities to demodulate the digital signal, and get the FIC (fast information channel, i.e., channel, traffic information, metadata etc), and the MSC (main service channel, i.e., mostly the MPEG transport streams) of the bouquets you've tuned into.

Seeing that you probably have a PC/laptop, investment in this route is laughably low: get an [RTL-SDR](https://osmocom.org/projects/rtl-sdr/wiki/Rtl-sdr) dongle ([possible source, nice packaging](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/buy-rtl-sdr-dvb-t-dongles/)), an investment running from anywhere between 7€ to 40€, and a good antenna for your bands of interest. That's it. Then download welle.io, verify operation, and if you want something that's very modular but might not sync as nicely as welle.io, try gr-dab, which is basically a transmitter / receiver experimenter's toolkit.

There you have the raw MPEG data stream, as transmitted from the radio transmitter. Note that most, if not all, of these MPEG audio codecs are *not* part of what is standards-compliant codecs for Bluetooth headsets, so you *will* have to transcode them anyways. "HE-AAC" is not the full specification of what happens audio-wise on DAB+; DAB+ MPEG transport streams may carry any combination of {MPEG-4 AAC, HE-AAC, HE-AACv2, AAC-LD, AAD-ELD, MPEG Layer 2, MPEG Layer 3}-encoded audio, and I think of these, Bluetooth A2DP only supports MPEG-4 AAC, which is probably not very common in modern radio stations.

> I was looking into the Silicon Labs Si4684 chip

That product line was bought by Skyworks, so no longer a Silicon Labs, but a Skyworks Si4684; just in case you need to figure out where to buy these. (Honestly, the only not "castle in the sky" source I could find was [mouser](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Skyworks-Solutions-Inc/SI4684-A10-GM?qs=p9T7GgSe1IFl%2FK1mJ61MOg%3D%3D).)

Note that buying the Si4684 solves the complexity of getting to the bits and decoding them; that's not a bad trade off. If you, however, have spare compute power in your system anyways (so, some half-to-unused arm Cortex-M4F core at 100 MHz, for example, or because there's some Linux-running SoC anyways), and feel up to the task of implementing your own radio receiver processing, that'd be fun and give you loads of flexibility. You will need to build/get a radio frontend that can do 2.048 MS/s and has a ~ 1.6 MHz frontend bandwidth (for optimum results).